# Retaining Data across multiple promise chains

Tags: javascript, scope, promise

I am learning promises, so I decided to play around with extending them. Everything is working except I am having a hard time figuring out how to make a value persist across all functions.

My goal is to find the count of the called functions from this promise, but each call creates a new one and I am having trouble finding a way to pass the value in. I tried adding a constructor which will have a value passed in, but it doesn't seem to work as I expect. I assume this is due to me misunderstanding the scope of "this".

to sum it up, each of my functions "init", "add" and "commit" should all up front add 1 to the "total number of steps" variables, which right now in this example is "i". With that I want to be able to say, I am on step 1 of 3, step 2 of 3 etc...

```
class Repo {
    constructor(setup) {
        this.s = {};
        this.s._progress = { "total":0, "count":0 };
        this.s._logging = { "enabled":true, "location":"console", "pretty":true, "verbose":false, "tabCount":0 };
        this.s._remoteInfo = { "name":"", "url":"" };
        this.s._localInfo = { "path":"" };

        this.s._logReset = () => {
            this.s._logging.tabCount = 0;
        };

        this.s._log = (message, tabCount) => {
            if(this.s._logging.enabled) {
                let tabs = '';

                if(this.s._logging.pretty) {
                    for(let i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) { tabs = tabs + '\t' };
                }

                if(this.s._logging.location == 'console') { console.log(tabs, message); }
                else {
                    //TODO: implement the file location to output
                }
            }
        };

        this.s._progressReset = () => {
            this.s._progress.total = 0;
            this.s._progress.count = 0;
        };

        this.s._addProgressTotal = () => {
            this.s._progress.total++;
            console.log(this.s._progress.total)
        }

        this.s._addProgress = () => {
            this.s._progress.count++;
            console.log('Progress is ' + this.s._progress.count + ' out of ' + this.s._progress.total)
        }
    }

    //Starts the promise chain and passes in the settings to be used.
    start() {
        this.s._logReset();
        this.s._progressReset();

        return new RepoPromise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.s._log('Start Log: <time>',0)
            resolve(this.s);
        });
    }
}

class RepoPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor, val) {
        let e = executor || function (res, rej) { res('')};
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            return e(resolve, reject);
        });

        this.i = val || 0;
    }

    end() {
        const returnValue = super.then((s) => {
            return new RepoPromise((resolve, reject) => {
                s._log('End Log: <time>',0)
                resolve(s);
            }, this.i);
        });
        return returnValue;
    }

    init() {
        //I know I need to add 1 to "i" here, but it won't work
        const returnValue = super.then((s) => {
            return new RepoPromise((resolve, reject) => {
                s._log('git init',1);
                s._addProgress();
                resolve(s, '')
            }, ++this.i);
        });
        return returnValue;
    };

    add() {
        //I know I need to add 1 to "i" here, but it won't work
        const returnValue = super.then((s) => {
            return new RepoPromise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    s._log('git add',1);
                    s._addProgress();
                    resolve(s,'');
                    //reject('Add Failed')
                }, Math.random() * (10000 - 1000) + 1000);
            },++this.i);
        });
        return returnValue;
    }

    commit() {
        //I know I need to add 1 to "i" here, but it won't work
        const returnValue = super.then((s) => {
            return new RepoPromise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    s._log('git commit -m "message"',1);
                    s._addProgress();
                    resolve(s, 'Finished');
                }, Math.random() * (5000 - 1000) + 1000);
            }, ++this.i);
        });
        return returnValue;
    }

    then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        const returnValue = super.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var p = new Repo('')
.start()
    .init()
    .add()
    .commit()
.end()
.catch(
    x => {console.log('it broke: ' + x)}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've pointed out, there isn't *one* promise in the chain, every `then` and `catch` returns a *new* promise. So don't try to retain the state in the `RepoPromise`, retain it in the object that you pass through the chain as the resolution value: `s`.

Re your second parameter to `RepoPromise` constructor: You can't reliably do that, because you aren't in control of every time that constructor is called. Remember, that constructor is called when you call `then` or `catch`. Which is another reason to pass the value around on `s` instead. :-) Just for completeness, here's an illustration of the fact that the constructor gets called within `Promise`:

```js
class MyPromise extends Promise {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    console.log("MyPromise constructor called");
  }
}

MyPromise.resolve()
  .then(val => val)
  .then(val => val)
  .then(val => val);
```

---

A couple of side notes:

1. This:

   ```
   super((resolve, reject) => {
       return e(resolve, reject);
   });
   ```

   can be written simply as:

   ```
   super(e);
   ```
2. This doesn't do anything and can just be removed:

   ```
   then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
       const returnValue = super.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
       return returnValue;
   }
   ```

---

I was a bit dense understanding the question, but now I get it: You want to increase `s._progress.total` for each call to `init`/`add`/`commit`, and increase `s._progress.count` when each `then`/`catch` callback is called.

Here's a simplified exmaple that just uses `then` and `catch` rather than adding `init`, `add`, and `commit` but you can easily apply the pattern to add those if you like.

The solution was to keep the status tracker (`s`) on the promise object, and insert ourselves into the various ways new promises are created (`then`, `catch`) so we copy the tracker from the old promise to the new one. We share the tracker across all of these promises, e.g., the tracker from the root promise tracks everything from there forward. See comments:

```js
"use strict";

// For tracking our status
class Status {
    constructor(total = 0, count = 0) {
        this.id = ++Status.id;
        this.total = total;
        this.count = count;
    }
    addCall() {
        ++this.total;
        return this;
    }
    addProgress() {
        ++this.count;
        return this;
    }
    toString() {
        return `[S${this.id}]: Total: ${this.total}, Count: ${this.count}`;
    }
}
Status.id = 0;

// The promise subclass
class RepoPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super(executor);
        this.s = new Status();
    }
    // Utility method to wrap `then`/`catch` callbacks so we hook into when they're called
    _wrapCallbacks(...callbacks) {
        return callbacks.filter(c => c).map(c => value => this._handleCallback(c, value));
    }
    // Utility method for when the callback should be called: We track that we've seen
    // the call then execute the callback
    _handleCallback(callback, value) {
        this.s.addProgress();
        console.log("Progress: " + this.s);
        return callback(value);
    }
    // Standard `then`, but overridden so we track what's going on, including copying
    // our status object to the new promise before returning it
    then(onResolved, onRejected) {
        this.s.addCall();
        console.log("Added: " + this.s);
        const newPromise = super.then(...this._wrapCallbacks(onResolved, onRejected));
        newPromise.s = this.s;
        return newPromise;
    }
    // Standard `catch`, doing the same things as `then`
    catch(onRejected) {
        this.s.addCall();
        console.log("Added: " + this.s);
        const newPromise = super.catch(...this._wrapCallbacks(onRejected));
        newPromise.s = this.s;
        return newPromise;
    }
}

// Create a promise we'll resolve after a random timeout
function delayedGratification() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(_ => {
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 1000);
    });
}

// Run! Note we follow both kinds of paths: Chain and diverge:
const rp = RepoPromise.resolve();
rp.then(delayedGratification)   // First chain
  .then(delayedGratification)
  .then(delayedGratification);
rp.catch(delayedGratification)  // Second chain
  .then(delayedGratification);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code suggestions, I will make the changes. The only problem I found with using the "resolve" to pass around my settings ("S") is that it forces it to be inside the "then" calls which won't allow me to add up the number of calls up front.

I need to add values at the beginning of each call BEFORE the then is returned to be chained. So unless there is a mechanic to do that I am not sure how. Which is why I tried to move to the constructor way, which is obviously giving me problems.

Comment: @Krum110487: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean about adding up the calls "up front"...?

Comment: So when add/init/commit is called, I comments where I would like add 1 to the count. If the addition happened there it would add it up 3 times before the first call even finished, because we are waiting on the promise callback. Because Add/init/commit will continue on after they return the promise, I want the count to occur in the add/init/commit functions themselves, instead of in the promise they return.

Comment: @Krum110487: I may be being dense. You said *"My goal is to find the count of the called functions from this promise..."* What functions, specifically, do you want to count the calls to? `add`? Or `then`/`catch`? (There's only a final `catch` in your example, after `commit`, so maybe your goal is to count `add` calls?)

Comment: Well each function I call is really just a wrapper for the super.then( (s) => {}..)

so in a way when I call "add" it is really then(...add code...), so the s is returned through the "then" call. This is fine for me keeping track of which step the process is currently on, but not how many steps there are to go. If I handle this with s and adding it inside the then calls, it will only update the total number of calls at the same time it updates which function you are on. I want each function add/init/commit to immediately add 1 to the total before returning their "then" function.

Comment: @Krum110487: I think I get it now. :-) You want to increase `s._progress.total` for each call to `init`/`add`/`commit`, and increase `s._progress.count` for each `then`/`catch` callback?

Comment: Exactly! If only I could have put it so simply originally.

Comment: @Krum110487: That was an interesting problem. I've added a solution to the end which hopefully proves useful.