# Node Unhandled Promise issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I previously asked the question found here:
[Retaining Data across multiple promise chains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384071/retaining-data-across-multiple-promise-chains/43384314#43384314)

I ended up using T.J. Crowder's answer for my base code and have made many many changes since. But I noticed something weird in node which I cannot seem to overcome. I went back to the base code he provided and the issue seems to be there as well.

Here is the example:

```
"use strict";

// For tracking our status
class Status {
    constructor(total = 0, count = 0) {
        this.id = ++Status.id;
        this.total = total;
        this.count = count;
    }
    addCall() {
        ++this.total;
        return this;
    }
    addProgress() {
        ++this.count;
        return this;
    }
    toString() {
        return `[S${this.id}]: Total: ${this.total}, Count: ${this.count}`;
    }
}
Status.id = 0;

// The promise subclass
class RepoPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super(executor);
        this.s = new Status();
    }
    // Utility method to wrap `then`/`catch` callbacks so we hook into when they're called
    _wrapCallbacks(...callbacks) {
        return callbacks.filter(c => c).map(c => value => this._handleCallback(c, value));
    }
    // Utility method for when the callback should be called: We track that we've seen
    // the call then execute the callback
    _handleCallback(callback, value) {
        this.s.addProgress();
        console.log("Progress: " + this.s);
        return callback(value);
    }
    // Standard `then`, but overridden so we track what's going on, including copying
    // our status object to the new promise before returning it
    then(onResolved, onRejected) {
        this.s.addCall();
        console.log("Added: " + this.s);
        const newPromise = super.then(...this._wrapCallbacks(onResolved, onRejected));
        newPromise.s = this.s;
        return newPromise;
    }
    // Standard `catch`, doing the same things as `then`
    catch(onRejected) {
        this.s.addCall();
        console.log("Added: " + this.s);
        const newPromise = super.catch(...this._wrapCallbacks(onRejected));
        newPromise.s = this.s;
        return newPromise;
    }
}

// Create a promise we'll resolve after a random timeout
function delayedGratification() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(_ => {
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 1000);
    });
}

// Run! Note we follow both kinds of paths: Chain and diverge:
const rp = RepoPromise.resolve('Test');
rp.then(function(scope) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('  Rejected')
        reject(scope)
    })
})
.catch(e => {console.log('Never Makes it')})
```

when I run this with: `node test.js` I get the following output

```
Added: [S1]: Total: 1, Count: 0
Added: [S1]: Total: 2, Count: 0
Added: [S1]: Total: 3, Count: 0
Progress: [S1]: Total: 3, Count: 1
  Rejected
(node:29364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Test
(node:29364) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Notice that the console log for `"never makes it"` is not present, also note, I already fixed the issue with `catch` running twice as it is simple syntactic sugar for `then(null, function(){})`, so you can ignore that.

Why is catch not working as I expect? When I do this with a normal promise, there are no issues, like below. So I know for a fact that the `_wrapCallbacks` is causing the issue, I am just not sure why, or how to fix it.

```
const rp = Promise.resolve('Test');
rp.then(function(scope) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('  Rejected')
        reject(scope)
    })
})
.catch(e => {console.log('Makes it')})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `catch` implementation of your promise doesn't work. Notice that the native `catch` is implemented as `return this.then(null, callback)` - calling `super.catch` will just direct back to your `then` implementation.

And your `then` implementation has a major fault: it doesn't like to get a `null` argument before a function. Observe what happens in the above call when you're doing this:

```
_wrapCallbacks(...callbacks) {
    return callbacks.filter(c => c).map(…);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
then(onResolved, onRejected) {
    …
    const newPromise = super.then(...this._wrapCallbacks(onResolved, onRejected));
    …
}
```

That'll simply remove the `null` from the array of arguments and pass the `onrejected` callback as `onfulfilled` instead. You'll want to drop the `filter` and use a ternary in the mapping function instead:

```
_wrapCallbacks(...callbacks) {
    return callbacks.map(c => typeof c == "function"
      ? value => this._handleCallback(c, value)
      : c);
}
```

Also you can just drop the overridden `catch`.

Comment: Yes I already dropped the overridden catch, thank you for that, I was always confused as to why he used filter, but I see now. This was exactly my issue, I knew it was something with that function. I suppose I need to re-learn filter/map. THANKS!

Comment: Tbh, I wouldn't have used `filter`/`map` at all, but just called `super.then(this._wrapCallback(onFulfilled), this._wrapCallback(onRejected));`

Comment: Agreed, I just realized I have a fundamental misunderstanding of filter/map's as I rarely use them, knowing that null was dropped off would have helped me understand what was going on.