# Promise override causes then calls to error

Tags: javascript, class, promise

I have the following sample code.

```
class test extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super(executor)
    }

    static getPromise() {
        return new test((res, rej) => {
            res(true)
        })
    }
}

let t = test.getPromise()
t.then(value => {console.log("Works")}, 
       value => {console.log("Works")})
```

this works just fine, but if I were to put the same function directly into the super function, it throws an error.

```
class test extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super((res, rej) => {
            res(true)
        })
    }

    static getPromise() {
        return new test((res, rej) => {
            res(true)
        })
    }
}

let t = test.getPromise()
t.then(value => {console.log("Works")}, 
       value => {console.log("Works")})
```

the error is `TypeError: Promise resolve or reject function is not callable` Why is this happening, aren't these two pieces of code equivalent?

My goal is to simplify use of my library by simply having:

```
let t = new test()
t.then(value => {console.log("Works")}, 
       value => {console.log("Works")})
```

I understand this is not much of a simplification, I am ok with keeping the static function if required, but I am more curious as to why this is not working.

my questions are:

1. Why are these not equivalent, and why is this erroring?
2. How can I make this work as I expect?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Bergi, I came to the realization that the promise class I am overriding is using the test constructor for the "then" functions. While I was assuming it was using the original constructor. It is obvious in hindsight, but my fix ended up being simply adding this to the constructor.

```
if(!executor) executor = (res, rej) => { res(true) }
```

Comment: Why are you doing nothing with `options` and what is `scope`?

Comment: that is me not cleaning up my code for the example correctly, let me do a bit of corrections.

Comment: Yes please. Only post runnable code that actually causes the problem you describe. Post your complete original code if necessary.

Comment: Note that the functions you pass to `.then` are wrong: they don't give you `resolve` and `reject` as parameters, they give you the resolution value or error.

Comment: @Bergi well, the original code did run, I did run it, it was just not cleaned up.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, I had promises in there, let me make that more clear and clean that up.

Comment: @Krum110487 the original code would have had a `ReferenceError` for `scope`. It's also not clear how you are running this because class fields AFAIK are not natively implemented in any browser. Are you using babel?

Comment: It worked for me when I ran it both in node and chrome, and I just re-tested it, it worked again. But that is neither here or there, I cleaned it up. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are these not equivalent, and why is this erroring?

Your overridden constructor does never call the `executor` and pass it the promise resolving functions (`resolve` and `reject`). They are important! You cannot subclass `Promise` and change the interface like that.

Why does this throw an error when you call `new test()` that doesn't use the constructor? It does not. It throws the error when you call `t.then(…)`, which tries to construct a new promise (for its return value) and uses `t`'s constructor for that. It does pass a proper executor callback, and expects it to be called synchronously with `resolve` and `reject` - which your code does not do. After the call, it bitches about not having got two functions.

> How can I make this work as I expect?

Don't use promise subclassing. There's no reason for it. You just want to have a normal function that returns a promise. Use

```
const test = {
    getPromise() {
        return Promise.resolve(true)
    }
};
test.getPromise().then(…);
```

or

```
function test() {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}
test().then(…);
```

Comment: I thought calling the super function will call the original constructor that the promise has, does it not?

Comment: @Krum110487 Yes it does. You're doing that fine. You just ignore the `executor` argument

Comment: oh shit, it is so obvious now, the promise is being used for the then function and I have my own function showing up....

Comment: Also, the reason I am subclassing the promise is because I am extending promise functionality to make my own, I have simply been using the static function as I couldn't figure out my stupidity :-), I fixed it by simply adding `if(!executor) executor = (res, rej) => { res(scope) }`

Comment: I'd be curious how you are extending them that you require subclassing. Can you link your project's whole code maybe?

Comment: it is still a major work in progress, but essentially I added events to allow for progress updates and determining max number of steps as well as where you are in the process. I actually have another question that gave me quite a bit of code as my starting point (I have added a ton more, including some bug fixes to the original code provided) but here is the link to that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384071/retaining-data-across-multiple-promise-chains

Comment: also, go easy on my code, I started this small project because I wanted to learn promises in and out :)

Comment: I think this answer needs more elaboration. "You cannot change an interface like that". Why not? It's my subclass, I can assume that only I am calling the constructor. (Or the parent class is doing something really complicated and unnecessary, in which case why do we use it.)

Comment: @personal_cloud Changing the interface is a violation of the [Liskov substituton principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), meaning it's no longer a subclass. No, you can not assume that you are the only one to call the constructor, `.constructor` is a publicly accessible property. And as my answer states, "*`then` tries to construct a new promise and uses the `.constructor` for that*", attempting to create another instance of your subclass.