# Typescript: Inheriting from Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Using Typescript ^3.8.  I am building a `BrokenPromise` class which extends`Promise` but is supposed to return a promise that never resolves.  Before building the class, this is how I built such a promise:

```js
const p = new Promise(resolve => {});
```

Figuring this would be simple, I tried this:

```js
class BrokenPromise extends Promise {
  constructor() {
    super(resolve => {});
  }
}
```

The Typescript compiler doesn't complain, so then I try to use it like so:

```js
Promise.race([
  new BrokenPromise().then(() => { log('SHOULD NEVER RUN'); }),
  sleep(2).then(() => { log('SHOULD ALWAYS WIN THE RACE') })
]);
```

But the `BrokenPromise.then` fails with this error:

> TypeError: Promise resolve or reject function is not callable at Promise.then

Why is this happening?  The code below works but smells:

```js
class BrokenPromise extends Promise {
  super(resolve => {});

  return new Promise(resolve => {});
}
```

### Update 1: Solved (thanks Nick Parsons)

```js
export class BrokenPromise extends Promise<any> {
  constructor(executor = (resolve, reject?) => {}) {
    super(executor);
  }
}
```

The problem with my original code was that `.then` behind the scenes passes an executor function to the constructor and expects `resolve` or `reject` to be called, but my code ignored it.  The new code above passes it on to the parent constructor where it gets treated as expected.

Comment: I think you should try declaring your promise first then calling `.then`.
I don't think you can call `new Promise().then`.
Maybe try `const p =  new BrokenPromise` and then call `p().then`

Comment: Hi.  At the bottom of my post, I explained that if I change the constructor of `BrokenPromise`, then the same `new BrokenPromise().then()` works.  So something else is going on

Comment: Have you seen this thread: [Promise override causes then calls to error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47312427), you can probably make it work by using something like: `constructor(executorFn = resolve => {}) { super(executorFn);}`, or just don't subclass the promise (like the linked answer suggests)

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks, you helped me solve my issue. if you'd like to get credit for this, please add it as an Answer to the post.

Comment: @BeetleJuice nw, might be better to close as a dupe of the linked questions 